# Obtain all files that are over 1gb in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystems

I'm trying to get all the non system files on my computer to find out what files are over 1gb via a **WinForms application**.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
        const long b500mb = 65536000;
        const long b1gb = 134217728;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //https://unitconverter.io/gigabits/bytes/1
        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cDriveDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\").GetDirectories()
                .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
                .Where(w => w.FullName != @"C:\Windows")
                .Select(f => f.FullName)
                .ToList();

            var filesOver1Gb = new List<FileInfo>();

            foreach (var item in cDriveDirectories)
            {
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(item);

                var files = d.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(w => w.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Normal)
                                                                                 && w.Length > b1gb).ToList();

                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    filesOver1Gb.Add(file);
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I get around this error?

**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\history' is denied.'**

Comment: What project is this being used in ? A web project or console or winforms?

Comment: @Zee: I updated the question, sorry. WinForms.

Comment: @If debugging, try running VisualStudio as an administrator. If executing from an .exe run with admin previleges. ALso put a try, catch block around your method to catch the exception so your program doesn't crash.

Comment: @Zee. thanks. Answer posted! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

After @zee's help:

I VS as an admin and then put a try/catch around the line of code that was failing and continued.

This code will obtain the information I need!

```
        const long b500mb = 65536000;
        const long b1gb = 134217728;
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //https://unitconverter.io/gigabits/bytes/1
        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cDriveDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\").GetDirectories()
                .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
                .Where(w => w.FullName != @"C:\Windows")
                .Select(f => f.FullName)
                .ToList();

            var filesOver1Gb = new List<FileInfo>();
            IList<string> unauthorizedFiles = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in cDriveDirectories)
            {
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(item);

                var files  = new List<FileInfo>();
                try
                {
                    files = d.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(w => !w.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System)
                                                                                     && w.Length > b1gb).ToList();
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    // ignore error and continue to process files over 1gb.
                }


                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    filesOver1Gb.Add(file);
                }
            }

            // get the total count in bytes to find out how many gbs we have etc.
            long totalOver1Gb = 0;
            foreach (var file in filesOver1Gb)
            {
                totalOver1Gb = totalOver1Gb + file.Length;
            }
        }
```